# How to invoke a JAR resides in the maven local repository?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, continuous-deployment

As part of a CI/CD process, I'm pulling a JAR from a maven repository (Sonatype nexus)

Now, I'd like to simply "java -jar" it.

What is the simplest way to do it?

Should I just use the command `java -jar ${MAVEN_HOME}/repository/com/company/path/to/my/x.jar`?

Or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a sh file and this to download jar

```
wget --user USERNAME --password PASSWORD url of the nexus where the jar is uploaded

java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar name of the jar.jar
exec "$@"
```

> The Next step will help you to download jar to another project

In your pom.xml you need to add `repository` tag

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
       <id>remote</id>
       <url>Url where you have hosted the jar</url>
     </repository>
</repositories>
```

Also, you need to add setting.xml if your remote is password protected

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
 <servers>
    <server>
      <id>remote</id>
      <username>***</username> //username
      <password>****</password> //password
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

After that add dependency in your pom.xml, it will download the jar to you local m2 folder

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>group id of project</groupId> 
            <artifactId>artifact of project</artifactId>    //artifact of your jar
            <version>version of your project</version>
        </dependency>
```

This `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version` that you need to add when you will create the jar